# How to detect the use of the virtual back button?

Tags: android

I use fragment, and i want detect backbutton to stop exiting the app and do something else.
BUT.... all code i've try doesn't work:
I've test in debug mode, with breakpoint into function, but it seem none of them are called when i press the back button, and the app exit.

```
       public class MyListFragment extends Fragment implements OnTouchListener, OnFocusChangeListener, OnClickListener, OnKeyListener{

// Test 1   
         public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                    String a=null;
                    switch(keyCode)
                    {
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAMERA:
                     Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Pressed Camera Button",                             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1:
                     Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Pressed 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME:
                     Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Pressed Home Button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                     Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Pressed Back Button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    }
                    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
                    {
                    a=a;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
// Test 2
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String b=null;
        b=b;

        return false;
    }
// Test 3    
    public void onBackPressed() {
        String b=null;
        b=b;    
    }
// Test 4    
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        String b=null;
        b=b;
        return false;   
    }
    }
```

I don't Kown why nothing working, any ideas?

Comment: add @Override on public void onBackPressed() { }

Comment: When i add @ Override eclipse said: "te methode onBackPressed() of MyListFragment must override or implement a supertype method.....

Comment: posted a solution try that if that solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

This method will give you solution of `Activity`.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: When i add @ Override eclipse said: "te methode onBackPressed() of MyListFragment must override or implement a supertype method.....

Comment: oh sorry for not mentioning, you need to place this code in your parent activity having `FragmentActivity`. You can place there and make a `listener` which call fragment to do something.

Answer (score 0):

When you are transitioning between Fragments, call addToBackStack() as part of your FragmentTransaction:

```
FragmentTransaction tx = fragmentManager.beginTransation();
tx.replace( R.id.fragment, new MyFragment() ).addToBackStack( "tag" ).commit();
```

If you require more detailed control (i.e. when some Fragments are visible, you want to suppress the back key) you can set an OnKeyListener on the parent view of your fragment:

```
fragment.getView().setOnKeyListener( new OnKeyListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onKey( View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event )
    {
        if( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK )
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
} );
```